# Is there a way to configure credentials for a private npm registry without having to store plain text in ~/.npmrc?

Tags: security, npm

According to the [official documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/npmrc#auth-related-configuration) it seems to guide users to store the auth in plain text in `~/.npmrc`.

I was wondering if there is a way to configure the credentials for the npm registry without having to store plain text in `~/.npmrc`.

For example, in git we can use the various git credential helpers to store your credentials in a secure way. Similarly, docker and other container services have their own credential helpers. [Link](https://github.com/containers/image/blob/0b5d951509731c1de1372d3935a5d9fa5a8c50c6/docs/containers-auth.json.5.md)